# Telerik MVC Grid Custom Column Image Button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, telerik, grid

I working with Telerik MVC Grid and i'm trying to change the button image of a custom column.

```
column.Command(Sub(cmd)
                   cmd.Custom("Editar").ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage).HtmlAttributes(New With{ .class="btnDelete"}).DataRouteValues(Sub(route)
                                                                                                                         route.Add(Function(x) x.idPedidoDocumentacao).RouteKey("idPedidoDocumentacao")
                                                                                                                     End Sub).Action("DetalhePedido", "Pedido").SendDataKeys(True)
                            End Sub).Width("5%").Title("Editar")
```

I create a class in my css file:

```
.btnDelete
```

{

```
background-position:0px 0px;
background:url(/Images/delete.png);
```

}

Can anyone help me figure this out?
Thks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to override the background image that the button is using. In case of Bare Image, it creates a span like this

```
<span class="t-icon t-add" />
```

So you'll need to create a class on your css stylesheet

```
span.t-icon.t-add{
background-image: ur('yourimagepath');
}
```

Be aware that Telerik uses sprites on its icons, so you'll need to override the background position too